# How do i get a batch file calling a powershell script that imports a module and writes results to a file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, splunk

I am working on a batch file that will: run powershell -> import activedirectory -> place a query ->write results to a text file, which will ultimately be ingested by Splunk.

My current powershell script is:

```
get-adcomputer -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' | select DistinguishedName | export-csv -append -path &"D:\Ingest Files\output.txt"
```

This works fine in cmd, if I first say:

```
powershell -noexit import-module activedirectory
```

However, when I put it into a batch script, based on what appears to be proper syntax, it throws an error that ampersands aren't allowed:

```
powershell -noexit import-module activedirectory -command "& {get-adcomputer -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' | select DistinguishedName | export-csv -append -path &"D:\Ingest Files\output.txt"}"
```

I also, after much tinkering, found that this doesn't error, but closes cmd and doesn't actually write to the file:

```
    powershell -noexit import-module activedirectory; get-adcomputer -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' | select DistinguishedName | export-csv -append -path &"D:\Ingest Files\output.txt"
```

I feel like I am just barely missing with the syntax, but it is seemingly impossible to diagnose.  I think the problem arises because I am trying to import the module, but when I remove that portion I still have the ampersand not allowed.  Is there a better way to do this, or do I just need a minor tweak?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, assuming the script itself is correct, you should be able to do this:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "& { import-module activedirectory; get-adcomputer -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' | select DistinguishedName | export-csv -append -path 'D:\Ingest Files\output.txt' }"
```

There may still be issues with the quoting, but that's easily fixed with escape characters

Comment: I will definitely check this, because I would prefer them to reside in the same file.

Comment: It says unrecognized command "enabled.."  Luckily, I found the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.  I created a PowerShell script that contained:

```
import-module activedirectory; get-adcomputer -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' | select DistinguishedName | export-csv -append -path D:\Ingest\test.txt
```

And my batch script was:

```
powershell -noexit -file d:\ingest\ou.ps1
```

Comment: Seems like you found the solution I was going to suggest. Using a .ps1 file is certainly the best way to handle all powershell scripts.